# assign a command to a variable containing file paths

Tags: bash, shell, command, variable-assignment

I've been searching an answer regarding commands assignated to variables in shell but without success. My script looks for a folder named `2015may` that has a file `4444444.xml`. The command `find /path/zipfolders -name "*${array[$((i+1))]}*" -exec grep -l "${array[$i]}" {} +` displays the following output using these parameters [`"2015may"`,`"44444444"`]: `path/filename_2015may.zip`. The problem is that this command returns `''` when assinging it to `$command`. I think I have a syntax mistake when assingning it to `$command`. I will appreciate your help to solving this issue.

**Script**

```
command=$(find /path/zipfolders -name "*${array[$((i+1))]}*" -exec grep -l "${array[$i]}" {} +)
echo "$command"
```

**Actual Output**

```
find /path/zipfolders -name "*${array[$((i+1))]}*" -exec grep -l "${array[$i]}" {} +
++ find /path/zipfolders -name '*2015may*' -exec grep -l 44444444 '{}' +
+ command=
+ echo ''
```

**Desired Output**

`path/filename_2015may.zip`

Comment: Don't you need `zgrep` to search inside the `zip` files.

Answer (score 0):

For assigning the command output to a shell variable, enclose the command in backticks(``). So your command will look like this:

```
    command=`(find /path/zipfolders -name "*${array[$((i+1))]}*" -exec grep -l "${array[$i]}" {} +)`
    echo $command
```

Comment: `$( )` (used in the question) is generally preferred over backticks, both because it's easier to read and because there are some oddities with escaping (and nesting) inside backticks. See [BashFAQ #82](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082).